# How do I add a legend for a secondary y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the `ggplot2` and `wesanderson` packages for plotting a graph which contains a line and bars. A sample of my data is presented as follows:

```
        Year  PIB     Variation
        1971  13032.36  0.0629264087            
        1972  13686.28  0.0501766372
        1973  15595.61  0.1395068638
        1974  17343.64  0.1120847469
        1975  19246.61  0.1097214887
        1976  20670.32  0.0739719878
        1977  21002.05  0.0160486146
        1978  22200.60  0.0570682386
        1979  23029.58  0.0373404322
        1980  23883.67  0.0370866512
        1981  25224.23  0.0561287273
        1982  25379.32  0.0061484533
        1983  25293.82 -0.0033688846
        1984  25957.86  0.0262530531
        1985  26979.30  0.0393499310
        1986  27914.07  0.0346476743
        1987  27841.75 -0.0025908081
        1988  29481.76  0.0589047025
        1989  29778.28  0.0100577442
        1990  30874.09  0.0367989689
        1991  32199.01  0.0429136535
```

I want to describe the evolution and the GDP growth rate using a secondary axis. so, my code is the following:

```
#For constructing the secondary axis
gdp_off_pib <- as.numeric(solve(
a=matrix(c(1,max(annual$Variation),1,min(annual$Variation)),
           nr=2,nc=2,byrow=TRUE),
b=matrix(c(max(annual$PIB),min(annual$PIB)),nc=1)))

graph_pib <- ggplot(annual, aes(x = Year)) + 
geom_col(aes(y = PIB, fill = "PIB")) +
scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("Zissou1", 3, type = "discrete"))+
geom_line(aes(y=(Variation*gdp_off_pib[2])+gdp_off_pib[1]), color="#F21A00"
           , size =0.8) +
scale_color_manual(values = wes_palette("Zissou1", 2, type = "continuous") )+
xlab("Year") +
ylab("Real GDP") + labs(color="Variables") +scale_y_continuous(    
   sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.- gdp_off_pib[1])/gdp_off_pib[2],
                      name = "GDP growth rate"))

graph_pib
```

The code above plots the following graph:

[image]

My problem is the right side, as you can see the graph does not explain that the red line is the growth rate and also the word fill appears.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To add the line to the legend, you need to give it a colour via an aesthetic, rather than hard-coding it:

  ```
  geom_line(aes(y = (Variation * gdp_off_pib[2L]) + gdp_off_pib[1L], color = 'GDP'))
  ```

  … and possibly apply a suitable palette, which your code tries — the problem is that you explicitly need to select the *second* colour in it, otherwise your line’s the same blue as the colums:

  ```
  wes_palette("Zissou1", 2L, type = "continuous")[2L]
  ```
- To remove the legend titles, set them to `NULL` or `""`:

  ```
  labs(color = NULL, fill = NULL)
  ```

The final code is:

```
palette = wes_palette("Zissou1", 2L, type = "continuous")

ggplot(annual, aes(x = Year)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = PIB, fill = "PIB")) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = palette[1L]) +
    geom_line(
        aes(y = (Variation * gdp_off_pib[2L]) + gdp_off_pib[1L], color = 'Growth'),
        size = 0.8
    ) +
    scale_color_manual(values = palette[2L]) +
    scale_y_continuous(
        sec.axis = sec_axis(
            ~ (. - gdp_off_pib[1L]) / gdp_off_pib[2L],
            name = "GDP growth rate"
        )
    ) +
    labs(y = 'Real GDP', color = NULL, fill = NULL)
```

[image: plot with legend]

But for a publication I would remove the legend entirely, and instead add the information about the axes into the axis title — either by giving them the appropriate colour, or by simply adding the words “bars” and “line” to the axis titles. For instance, the Economist, which (too) liberally uses secondary axes, colours both the axis title and the axis labels in the colour of the corresponding plot element:

[image: plot without legend]

Code:

```
ggplot(annual, aes(x = Year)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = PIB, fill = "PIB")) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = palette[1L], guide = FALSE) +
    geom_line(
        aes(y = (Variation * gdp_off_pib[2L]) + gdp_off_pib[1L], color = 'Growth'),
        size = 0.8
    ) +
    scale_color_manual(values = palette[2L], guide = FALSE) +
    scale_y_continuous(
        sec.axis = sec_axis(
            ~ (. - gdp_off_pib[1L]) / gdp_off_pib[2L],
            name = "GDP growth rate"
        )
    ) +
    ylab('Real GDP') +
    theme(
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = palette[1L]),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = palette[1L]),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = palette[2L]),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = palette[2L])
    )
```